# How do I make a HTML count up timer with the days:minutes:seconds without resetting on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html

I only have this code and I would want to make the code in a way that,
it would not reset its timing after I refresh the page, and that all users would see the same count-up timer without the timer resetting on page refresh. Anyone can help? :(

```
<label id="minutes">00</label>:<label id="seconds">00</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
    var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
    var totalSeconds = 0;
    setInterval(setTime, 1000);

    function setTime() {
        ++totalSeconds;
        secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
        minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
    }

    function pad(val) {
        var valString = val + "";
        if (valString.length < 2) {
            return "0" + valString;
        } else {
            return valString;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A few ideas: Cookies - save the variable in a cookie. Then you can save everything, and call it back on refresh. Database - This could be taxing and slow, but save things to a database (dont recommend). Good ol' text file - Constantly write to file the time, and read from it on page load.

Comment: Wait, this seems simple: Set an expire time supplied by the server. Then everyone is synchronized to the same expiration, and page refresh matters none. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

How about making a small modification to your code using the local storage of your browser.

```
var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");

// Retrieve the time. If time hasn't been saved it will return null and Number(null) ==> 0
var totalSeconds = Number(window.localStorage.getItem('totalSeconds'));

setInterval(setTime, 1000);

function setTime()
{
    //Save the time
    window.localStorage.setItem('totalSeconds', ++totalSeconds);

    secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds%60);
    minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/60));
}

function pad(val)
{
    var valString = val + "";
    if(valString.length < 2)
    {
        return "0" + valString;
    }
    else
    {
        return valString;
    }
}
```